# Combinatorics (?) Question

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have 4 digits that can be either 0 or 1. How many possible ways are there to list the diffrent combinations of 0's and 1's given that we want exactly two 0's and two 1's.

I was thinking 6, but I can't explain why.

0011
0101
0110
1010
1001
1100

I guess what I am trying to find out is the generic thinking of how I solve this problem for n digits (where n is an even natural number) when I want the digits to have n/2 0's and n/2 1's.

Answer (score 0):

The general case is the number of ways to choose $r$ things out of $n$ without respect to the order you choose them.  This gives the number of [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations) ${n \choose r}=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$  For the case $r=\frac n2$ you have the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) $\frac {(2r)!}{(r!)^2}$

Comment: I did know the theory about combination without order and how to compute it. What tricked me (and confused me) was that I didn't recognise that this particular problem was such a case. Cheers. PS more specifically I should have calculated the ways n/2 zeros can fit into n spots AND disregard ones. My problem in my thinking was that I mistankenly thought that I should have cared for ones as well.